@ngrx/signals How can I access the state of a featureStore which is consumed in a prefixed featureStore?
How can I access the state of a featureStore which is consumed in a prefixed featureStore?
I followed the example from this page (https://www.stefanos-lignos.dev/posts/ngrx-signals-store). But when I add a featureStore to the prefixed feature store, I can not access the state of the added featureStore.
I forked the mentioned example and added a "loadingFeatureStore", but as said, I can not use it. Is it possible to use a featureStore in a prefixed feature store? Do I have to change my types?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-oncrwa?file=src%2Fwith-clipboard.ts
